# How can I make a full-text search through AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, structured-logging

I use structured logging (hence: logging json strings) and I use a log identifier. So in my code, each log message has a unique identifier so that I can search in both directions: When I see a log message, I know where it comes from and when I expect log messages, I can search for this identifier.

My log-strings look like this:

```
{"log-id": "##_foo_bar-1", "message": "some explanation", "customer_id": 123}
```

I'm not too sure if I need to do something else with Cloudwatch, as it looks like this:

```
[2018-02-06 08:34:09,946]:[INFO]: {"log-id": "##_foo_bar-1", "message": "some explanation", "customer_id": 123}
```

Recently, I was looking for my identifier `##_foo_bar-1` and Cloudwatch told me:

[image]

I also tried:

```
{$.log-id = "##_foo_bar-1"}
```

No sucess. But it is for sure in the logs (I have seen it, after manually going through it).

How can I find it with the search function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the search term in quotes should work, like this: `"##_foo_bar-1"`

Searching for `{$.log-id = "##_foo_bar-1"}` should also work. I tried logging the same example statement you have in your question and this is what I get:

[image: CloudWatch logs screenshot]

Maybe your log message is not recognized as json, do you see it parsed and colorized like in my screenshot?

Comment: Thanks, I just made something wrong with structured logging!